# How commonly used are "sir" and "madam" in spoken English in America?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

Are "sir" and "madam" considered old-fashioned in spoken English in the US? Do native speakers use these words to address their teacher, boss, or customer in conversations?

Comment: Related: [In the US, on what occasion do you say "sir" when your listener is obviously younger than you?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/282970/130147)

Answer (score 5):

Customer - Yes. A shop clerk usually doesn't know the name of the customer. Using "sir" is a polite way to address a customer

Teacher - Perhaps.  It depends on the culture of the school. It is also common to use Mr or Ms with the teacher's last name. It is common at High School but rarer at university, though you may use "Professor". It is also more rarely used in grade school, in which you have one class teacher referred to as Mr/Ms/Miss...

Boss - Unlikely. It depends on the culture of the office, but usually you would know your boss's name and use that. And depending on the office culture you would probably use first names most often.

Learners tend to overuse "sir" and "madam".  In many situations a learner should use the person's name (with Mr/Ms+surname for formality).

Answer (score 3):

The words **sir** and **ma'am** are quite common in the US. **Ma'am** is the way we usually pronounce **madam** and has been for a long time. Most Americans are surprised to learn they are the same word.

If you are being polite, you will use **sir** to address any unfamiliar man over the age of 18 or so. You will use **miss** to address any unfamiliar woman between roughly 13 and 30. You will address any unfamiliar woman as **ma'am** who seems to be married or over the age of 40 or so. There is no clear dividing line, and we are often offended or confused when the woman is 30-50. In person, if we err on the side of caution, we are likely to to use **miss**. On the telephone, we usually say **ma'am**.

A cashier will address most customers as **sir** and **ma'am**.

A student should address most teachers as **sir** or **ma'am**. They don't always do so. They also use the **Mr./Miss/Mrs + surname** pattern.

Employees address bosses as **sir** or **ma'am** until they have been told otherwise. **Mr./Miss/Mrs + surname** is the norm in conversation, but you will normally say **Yes, sir** not, **Yes, Mr. Peterson**—unless that is the company culture.

By convention, female restaurant servers are addressed as **miss**.

In a fancy, high-priced restaurant, a female customer might be addressed as **madam.**

Some people still address letters to strangers in this way: **Dear sir or madam,** especially when sending a letter of job application. I personally find this absurd.